# Fetch ActiveRecord model for each key in array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an array of hashes with comment id and his title:

```
arr = [{comment_id: 1, title: 'Title 1'}, {comment_id: 5, title: 'Title 2'}]
```

For each hash I have to add new :key that contain active record model as value:

```
arr = [{comment_id: 1, user: #<User0x00007fd88dfe1b28>..., title: 'Title 1'},{comment_id: 5, user: #<User0x00005fd58dfe1a31>..., title: 'Title 2'}]
```

The first solution I found is to make a query for each hash:

```
arr.each do |h|
 h[:user] = Comment.find(h[:comment_id]).user
end
```

but will be much better to do it with single sql-query
something like:

```
comment_ids = arr.map {|h| h[:comment_id] }
users = User.joins(:comments).order('comments.id').where(comments: {id: comment_ids })

# so here I need to match User with comment_id from comment_ids
```

Would be nice if someone suggest solution to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would find the comments matching the comment IDs, but also `includes(:user)` (see [Rails eager loading guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)) so that we can get the user associated with a comment without needing an additional query:

```
comments = Comment.where(id: comment_ids).includes(:user)
```

From this point there are two ways you can go about things. First [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) (different than [ActiveRecord::Base#find](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class), by the way) to pick out the comment corresponding to a particular id, and then read the user from that comment record

```
arr.each do |h|
  comment = comments.find { |comment| comment.id == h[:comment_id] }
  h[:user] = comment.user
end
```

Another way is to use some enumerable manipulation to create a hash where keys are comment IDs, and values are user objects. See [index_by](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/Enumerable:index_by) and [transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values)

```
users_by_comment_id = comments.index_by(&:id).transform_values(&:user)

arr.each do |h|
  h[:user] = users_by_comment_id[h[:comment_id]]
end
```